# Fetch Facebook Posts for Public Page using Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to fetch Facebook posts for a public page using the Facebook SDK for iOS. I can't seem to figure out how to get  and then use the access token I need to make this request. Let's say it's the New York Times page. This shouldn't require any permissions, so I should be able to use the App Access Token...but again, I can't figure out how to get & use that.

The code I am using looks like this:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/nytimes/posts" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"DATA: %@", [result data]);
         NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error); 
     }];
```

I keep receiving an error saying that an access token is required.

Please help!

Answer (score -1):

It means it asking you a permission to access the public post in view did load method put one line  code like (readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email",@"user_friends",@"user_likes",@"user_groups"];)
, for more details see this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2.